# Simplest chat application for android

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, instant-messaging

I want to design a **simple chat application** in **Android**. I am really confused in which service I should choose among

- **XMPP**
- **WebSocket**
- **GCM**
- **Jabber**

*(Everyone is welcome to increase the options)*

The chat will be among two people only. Two specific devices. Can anyone guide me through the process or show a simple tutorial to accomplish the same?